# Assigning a value to long and float primitive types in Java

Tags: java

I have a question about declaring a long variable in Java:

This compiles: `long x = 10;`
This gives a compiler error: `long x = 1000000000000`
This compiles: `long x = 1000000000000L`
Why don't i need to put a L after the number in the first case? How does this relate to the compiler automatically casting a long to an int value (because  Iguess that is what's happening in the first example) ?

Also the same question about float's:

This doesn't compile: `float f = 10.1;`
This compiles: `float f = 10;`
This compiles: `float f = 10.1f;`

Why does the first example not compile? Why is the f-prefix not needed in the second example? And how does this relate with the complier automatically casting to a double?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because without the L suffix, the number is an int and 1000000000000 is too large for int

Comment: *"An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1)."* - 1000000000000 cannot fit into an `int`.

Comment: For the float, the compiler tells you why: "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numeric constants without any postfix have default types. If they are integer (i.e. they have no floating point), the default type is `int`. If they have a floating point, the default type is `double`.

Therefore an integer constant without the L suffix (which denotes a `long` literal) can't be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and the `double` constant `10.1` can't be assigned to a `float` variable without an explicit cast.

On the other hand, the `int` `10` can be assigned to a `float` variable, as well as the `float` `10.1f`.

Comment: Complete, and yet very brief. I like your style.